# Create a mock calling a constructor

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

Suppose I have the following class:

```
class Person {
  private String name;
  private Integer id;
  public Person(String name){
     this.name=name;
     this.id=random();
  }

  int random() {
     return new Random().nextInt();
  }
}
```

It's possible to create a partial mock for a `Person` class  by calling the constructor with mocked `random()` method?
I mean something like this:

```
Person a=EasyMock.createMockBuilder(Person.class)
                  .withConstructor(String.class)
                  .withArgs("Albina")
                  .addMockedMethod("random")
                  .createMock();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it differently: use dependency injection to "insert" a Random object:

```
public Person(Random rand, String name) { this.random = rand ...
```

and

```
public Person(String name) { this(new Random(), name) ...
```

Then you can create an ordinary object of your class; which would be using a mocked Random.

Very often, we think about "complicated" solutions to somehow test our production code. But that is the wrong approach: if your code is hard to test; then change your code!

Comment: Thank you. There is some solution.